# Can exFilterColumn be used with yadcf.initMultipleTables?

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10, yadcf

Can yadcf.exFilterColumn be used with yadcf.initMultipleTables?

I have been able to get each of these working individually but not together.

```js
var oTable,
    oTable2;

$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';

    oTable = $('#example1').DataTable({
    });

    oTable2 = $('#example2').DataTable({
    });

    yadcf.initMultipleTables([oTable, oTable2], [{
        column_number: [2],
        filter_type: 'multi_select',
        filter_container_id: 'multi-table-filter-2',
        select_type_options: { width: '180px' }
    },
    {
        column_number: [3],
        filter_type: 'multi_select',
        filter_container_id: 'multi-table-filter-3',
        select_type_options: { width: '180px' }
    },
    {
        column_number: [4],
        filter_type: 'multi_select',
        filter_container_id: 'multi-table-filter-4',
        select_type_options: { width: '180px' }
    }]);
    yadcf.exFilterColumn(oTable, oTable2, [[2, ['Sasori', 'Shino',]]]);

});
```